# How Terraform manage apply failure

Tags: terraform

i start learing Terraform and i'am confused in state management in Terraform.

I search in stackoverflow but i can't find a clear ansewer for my question

Does Terraform support rollback ? How we can manage terraform apply failure / by mistake ? restore the current state is enough to restore the disred infra state ?

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as rollback in terraform as there is in cloudformation. But to be honest, I think this is an advantage because rollbacks take time and substantially slow down the development feedback loop

If you apply and run into an error, you simply go from there. For example, say I want to create 5 ec2 instances and an IAM role. The IAM role creates properly, but the ec2 instances do not because you didn't provide subnet values for the ec2 instances.

Once your apply is finished, you will have a failure. However, your IAM role will exist, the ec2 instances will not exist. From there, you fix the error(s) that cause your failure, and go from there. This is nice because there's no need to continually create and destroy the IAM role just because the EC2 instances aren't creating.

Also, have a look at terraform state backends.  The s3 one is really good. https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/s3 This means that your state resides in S3 (rather than locally) and supports locking with dynamodb so that only one user can interact with state at a time.

Comment: Thanks , this look very clear ; what about already ressources ? i mean , i've already configured ressource and i would scale up these ressources , and the apply is fail (for example , no more CPU in my subscription per region ) , how i can resolve that ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow completely, sorry. Are you talking about importing existing resources, modifying existing ec2 resources (assuming AWS) to have more CPU, or trying to scale an auto scaling group out to the point where there's no more compute capacity in the region?